# How to append data in the Tableau Data Source tab?

Tags: database, append, tableau-api

I am using Tableau Desktop 10.1 version. I have more than one data set (excel workbooks) which I need to append in Tableau Data Source tab. All the excel workbooks have same sets of columns. I can place them one below the other in excel and load in to tableau. But my objective is to bring them one below the other in Tableau data source tab itself. I have successfully tried appending the data sets in tableau worksheets, but I wish to know if the same can be done in the Data Source tab. I have also tried using "New Union" functionality with the various available join types, but the data does not get appended as required. Is there any other way through which I can append the data one below the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First save the excel files in csv format. If you want to automate that conversion then look at csvkit.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by `"New Union" functionality with the various available join types, but the data does not get appended as required` ?

when you drag one sheet and Union over the other sheet it WILL append check the row count. its a inbuilt functionality available in tableau.

Comment: Yes, it will append provided I have my data in one excel file. In my case, there are multiple excel files. I don't see an option other than appending them under worksheet in tableau.